# Building a table from an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array stating salary of different sectors. I need to calculate and then create a table based on this . I'm really confused how to do it . Here is an example data

```
const data=[
['Euro','Tech'],
['USD','Tech'],
['GBX', 'Health'],
['Euro', 'Real Estate'], 
['GBX', 'Real Estate'].
]
```

Now I have to display the sector ,salary & total in the Table like this below:

| Sector | Euro | GBX | USD | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tech | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Health | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Real Estate | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| Total | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |

Could you help me with this. I'm using React table to display the data.

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried?

Comment: `let eur = 0;
  let usd = 0;
  let  gb = 0;
  for (let rowInd = 0; rowInd < data.length; rowInd++){
    const row = res[rowInd];
    for (let colInd = 0; colInd < row.length; colInd++){
      const salary = row[colInd]
      if (salary === 'EURO') {
        eur++;
      } else if(salary === 'USD'){
        usd++;
      } else {
        gb++
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: I started with adding up all the salary separately and I can see the total in the console but couldn't able to think how to proceed to display them in a table according the sector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the idea is to create a two dimensional array filled with zeros, then work through each item in the data array and increment the correct value in the two diminsional array based on a lookup using a map of sector names to indexes and a map of currency names to indexes.

Hopefully it helps, though I feel like there's probably a better way to do it.

```js
const data = [
  ['Euro','Tech'],
  ['USD','Tech'],
  ['GBX', 'Health'],
  ['Euro', 'Real Estate'], 
  ['GBX', 'Real Estate'],
  ['GBX', 'Health'],
];

const array_unique = (arr) => Array.from(new Set(arr));

const sectors = array_unique( data.map(([_, sector]) => sector) );
const currencies = array_unique( data.map(([currency]) => currency) ).sort();

const sector_map = Object.fromEntries(
  sectors.map((sector, index) => [sector, index])
);

const currency_map = Object.fromEntries(
  currencies.map((currency, index) => [currency, index])
);

// zero fill 2 dimensional array
const values_matrix = sectors.map( () => currencies.map(() => 0) );

// increment values in the 2 dimensional array for each item in the data array
// getting the row index and column index from the sector_map and currency_map
for(const [currency, sector] of data) {
  values_matrix[ sector_map[sector] ][ currency_map[currency] ]++;
}


// create rows for a table
const rows = [['Sector', ...currencies]];
for(const [index, sector] of sectors.entries()) {
  rows.push([sector, ...values_matrix[index]]);
}

console.log(rows.map((row) => row.join(',')));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to format data array

```
const data = [
  ['Euro', 'Tech'],
  ['USD', 'Tech'],
  ['GBX', 'Health'],
  ['Euro', 'Real Estate'],
  ['GBX', 'Real Estate'],
];

let res = {};
let currencies = [];
data.map((item) => {
  const [val, key] = item;
  res[key] ? res[key].push(val) : (res[key] = [val]);
  if (!currencies.includes(val)) currencies.push(val);
});

const rows = Object.keys(res); //Tech, Health, Real Estate

const table = new Array(rows.length);
let index = 0;

for (let row = 0; row < currencies.length; row++) {
  key = rows[row];
  const values = Object.values(res[key]);
  table[index] = { title: key, values: new Array(currencies.length) };
  for (let i = 0; i < currencies.length; i++) {
    const element = currencies[i];
    if (values.includes(element)) {
      table[index].values[i] = { title: element, value: 1 };
    } else {
      table[index].values[i] = { title: element, value: 0 };
    }
  }
  index++;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(table, null, 2));
```

result will be like this

```
[
  {
    "title": "Tech",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Euro",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "USD",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "GBX",
        "value": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Health",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Euro",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "USD",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "GBX",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Real Estate",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Euro",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "USD",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "GBX",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the above suggestion , but it didn't increment the value. As per the requirement we have to increase the values.

Comment: what the value to increment? do you mean totals?

Comment: I think they mean that if you were to add a second `['GBX', 'Health']` item to the data array it would still only have 1 in the GBX Health cell and they would want it to have 2.

Comment: @BenStephens thanks,

@SomdottaSarkar
you can just change this
```
if (values.includes(element)) {
      const sum = values.reduce((a, c) => {
        if (c === element) a++;
        return a;
      }, 0);

      table[index].values[i] = { title: element, value: sum };
    } else {
      table[index].values[i] = { title: element, value: 0 };
    }```